# How to get the content type model name using the slug field

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I would like to get the model name from the content type.

I have tried this ....

a=Module.objects.filter(slug="sales")

So it return SoftDeletionQueryset

So after that I just done the following

for x in a: print(x.content_type)

So it return "sales analytics". That is the content_type value in the Module.content_type field

I have the content_type values now ..... The content type model having the 3 fields right ? app_label,model,name So I want to get the model name according to the content_type values –

Here is my code

```
class Module(BaseModel, SoftDeletionModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Module Name"), max_length=50, default=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(
        _("Display Name"), max_length=50, default=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_module_id = models.ForeignKey("Module",
                                         blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(_("Order"), default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'modules'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.display_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question, but I will try to answer

You use `print()` and it returns `__str__` func result.

If you want to get the model name you have to use this code or content_type

```
modules = Module.objects.filter(slug="sales")
for m in modules:
   print(m.name)
   print(m.content_type)
```

If you mean exactly classname
For that use `.__class__.__name__` or `Module.__name__`

Comment: Hello I will explain it ......


I have the content_type values now .....

The content type model having the 3 fields right ?

app_label,model,name

So I want to get the model name according to the content_type values

Comment: Still unclear for me, sorry  
You want to make query to the Module table using content_type as a filter?
`Module.objects.filter(content_type__name="some_name")` ?